# Showing name of feature after click on VECTOR LAYER

Tags: vector, geojson, openlayers-3

I am new in Openlayers 3. I have vector layer importing from geojson file. I would like to show information about my feature after click on vector layer. 
Any idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these examples:

1) http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.1/examples/vector-layer.html?q=overlay

2) http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.1/examples/popup.html?q=overlay

Instead of putting the vector information next to the map, you put it in the popup `<div>` you created.

Answer (score 0):

I used the library from [here](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-popup) for this purpose. The sample code is

```
var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
map.addOverlay(popup);

//handling Onclick popup
map.on('click', function(evt) {
 var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
   function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });
 if (feature) {
    var coord = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    popup.show(coord, '<div><h2>Tilte</h2><p>' +feature.get('<property_in_single_quotes>')+ '</p></div>');  
}
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it works! I wrote in this way :              map.on('click', function(e) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature) {
    return feature;
  });
  
  
  var infoElement = document.getElementById('info');
  infoElement.innerHTML = feature ? feature.get('gml_id') : '';                  I would like only show more feature , not only 'gml_id' . How should I write it?

Comment: I think you can use jquery append() to append for that purpose along with feature.get('<watever_information>')

Comment: Where exacly i have to put append()?

Comment: Something like the following snippet

    `$("#info").append('<b>Title</b> : '+feature.get('gml_id')+'<br/>    <b>Title</b> : '+feature.get('gml_id_2'))`

Comment: Instend of  infoElement.innerHTML = feature ? feature.get('gml_id') : ''; use  this $("#info").append('<b>Title</b> : '+feature.get('gml_id')+'<br/><b>Title</b> : '+feature.get('gml_id_2')) .

Comment: Yes, try it... In my case i did not use append().

Comment: It works. But when I click another vector layer I 've still seen previous "info". I would like to after "click another layer" close previous info.Do you have ide how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to OL and Java script
There are stop points and coordinates for them, how can you make it so that by clicking on a vector object (stop) its name is displayed. Geolocation is tied to a specific coordinate

```
    var pointsStation = [     //координаты остановок
        {   id:111, name:'Красноярск АВ',
            cords:[92.905977,56.03295]
     var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new 
        ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(pointsStation[j].cords, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
                name: pointsStation[j].name,
                id: 'station-' + pointsStation[j].id
```

This is how stop names are set based on coordinates. you need to click on them to open a window and there will be the name of the stop, the time of arrival and departure specified